# WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection refused while establishing connection via PyRFC

Tags: python, vba, saprfc, pyrfc

I chosen PyRFC library to fulfill the task of connecting to SAP from Python. Everything is normal except the connection. The code stops and displays error message when it connects to SAP.

```
import pyrfc
def get_connection(connmeta):
print('Connecting ...', connmeta['ashost'])
return Connection(**connmeta)

TEST = { 'user' : 'XX',
'passwd' : 'XX',
'ashost' : 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
'sysnr' : '00',
'client' : '400',
'lang' : 'EN' }

conn = get_connection(TEST)
```

It throws:

> ERROR Message
>
> pyrfc._exception.CommunicationError: RFC_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE (rc=1): key=RFC_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE, message=
>
> LOCATION CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host XXX-XXXXXXX with Unicode
>
> ERROR partner 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3300' not reached
>
> TIME Tue Nov 13 16:33:59 2018
>
> RELEASE 721
>
> COMPONENT NI (network interface)
>
> VERSION 40
>
> RC -10
>
> MODULE nixxi.cpp
>
> LINE 3283
>
> DETAIL NiPConnect2: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3300
>
> SYSTEM CALL connect
>
> ERRNO 10061
>
> ERRNO TEXT WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
>
> COUNTER 2
>
> [MSG: class=, type=, number=, v1-4:=;;;]

It seems issue lies in the server's firewall. And I googled most answers like this on internet including SAP's community.

Then I telnet port of SAP' s IP and got timeout. It seems closed port causes connection failure.

But before using Python, I used VBA to fetch data from SAP. the configure in VBA is almost same as that in Python

```
Set R3 = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")  
    R3.Connection.System = "PRT"  
    R3.Connection.ApplicationServer = "XXX.XX.XX.XX" 
    R3.Connection.Client = "400" 
    R3.Connection.SystemNumber = "00" 
    R3.Connection.User = "XX"
    R3.Connection.Password = "XX" 
    R3.Connection.Language = "EN" 
    R3.Connection.Codepage = "1100"

retcd = R3.Connection.Logon(1, True) 
If retcd <> True Then  
   MsgBox "Logon failure" 
Else 
   MsgBox "Logon success" 
End If
```

It works fine but with slow efficiency, that's why I choose Python as a workaround. Anybody knows why VBA successes but Python fails?

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" is a standard TCP/IP error message which means that the port number is incorrect. Double check, whether the SystemNumber of your backend system is really "00".

Answer (score 0):

This message looks like it is a networking issue:

> Connection refused